# Unity coroutine not working as expected with WebRequest

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

This code is logging the `token` immediately after the web request when it should wait for the variable to be set. Here's the code:

```
public void ConnectToLiveKit(string Username, string RoomName){

        string query = $"?roomname={RoomName}&username={Username}";
        string fullUri = ServiceURL+query;
        StartCoroutine(GetToken(fullUri));
        Debug.Log($"Token: {m_Token}");
        // handle NO TOKEN here
        StartCoroutine(CreateOrJoinRoom(Username, RoomName));
    }

    IEnumerator GetToken(string uri)
    {
        Debug.Log("Getting Token at " + uri + " ...");
        // using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
        // {
            UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri);
            // Request and wait for the desired page.
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
            // while (!webRequest.result.Equals(UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)){
            //     yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            // }

            string[] pages = uri.Split('/');
            int page = pages.Length - 1;

            switch (webRequest.result)
            {
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError:
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.DataProcessingError:
                    Debug.LogError(pages[page] + ": Error: " + webRequest.error);
                    break;
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError:
                    Debug.LogError(pages[page] + ": HTTP Error: " + webRequest.error);
                    break;
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.Success:
                    Debug.Log(pages[page] + ":\nReceived: " + webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
                    m_Token = webRequest.downloadHandler.text;
                    break;
            }
            yield break;
        // }
    }
```

The `GetToken` coroutine should wait for the `UnityWebRequest` to end and set the token variable before moving on to the next line and logging the value of the variable. It doesn't ... it happens immediately and then a short time later I get the response from the web request logged with the token. The `CreateOrJoinRoom` method is called prematurely.

Comment: `StartCoroutine` does not block.  Move the log into the `GetToken` routine, after the token has been retrieved.

Comment: @hijinxbassist or use [UniTask](https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask) and go properly async ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StartCoroutine` does not block code, so the lines in `ConnectToLiveKit` are being executed with normal order and timing.

You can solve this by chaining together the routines like so:

```
public void ConnectToLiveKit(string Username, string RoomName)
{
    string query = $"?roomname={RoomName}&username={Username}";
    string fullUri = ServiceURL + query;

    StartCoroutine(ConnectRoutine(fullUri, Username, RoomName));
}
private IEnumerator ConnectRoutine(string uri, string username, string roomName)
{
    yield return FetchTokenRoutine(uri);

    Debug.Log($"Token: {m_token}");

    // Handle no token here..

    yield return CreateOrJoinRoom(username, roomName);
}
private IEnumerator FetchTokenRoutine(string uri)
{
    // Actual code here..
}
private IEnumerator CreateOrJoinRoom(string user, string roomName)
{
    // Actual code here..
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the fast response.